# Build some libraries locally but apt-get doesn't see them as installed

Tags: libimobiledevice

I've download, build and installed libimobiledevice-glue and libplist but apt-get doesn't see them. Can you suggest a solution ? I've run make install, so ...

```
sudo apt-get install ./libimobiledevice-glue-dev_1.1.0-1~exp1_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libimobiledevice-glue-dev' instead of './libimobiledevice-glue-dev_1.1.0-1~exp1_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libimobiledevice-glue-dev : Depends: libimobiledevice-glue-1.0-0 (= 1.1.0-1~exp1) but it is not installable
                             Depends: libplist-dev (>= 2.3.0) but 2.2.0-6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I expected that once build and installed, libimobiledevice-glue and libplist would be seen.